# Spring Security 6 and Spring Problem Details

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a question regarding the use of the RFC7807 ProblemDetails-type that was introduced in Spring 6 and the use of Spring Security 6 to validate JWT tokens.

**My hypothesis:**

When an invalid token is supplied to a secured endpoint, the application should return a 401 **and a ProblemDetails body**. However, I cannot seem to find any config options to turn on this ProblemDetails-body.

**What is actually happening:**

When an invalid token is supplied to a secured endpoint, the application returns a 401 **without a body**

Here is an example of my `SecurityFilterChain` bean:

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity, NTKeycloakAuthProperties ntKeycloakAuthProperties) throws Exception {

        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry -> {
                    authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers("/secured/**").authenticated()
                    authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll();
                })
                .oauth2ResourceServer(httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer -> {
                    httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.authenticationManagerResolver(
                            new JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver(ntKeycloakAuthProperties.getIssuers())
                    );
                })
                // Question: Should there exist something pre-built and easy configurable that can enable RFC7807-type error response bodies?
                .build();
    }
```

So in short; Is it possible to enable RFC7807-style error response bodies when using Spring Security 6?

Comment: Spring Security doesn't leverage the exception handling from Spring and does this itself. You would need to plug it into Spring Security (like https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-exceptionhandler#with-exceptionhandler). Next you would also need to extend the problem detail support to handle the Spring Security errors, by default it only handles the known Spring errors not the Spring Security ones.

Comment: @M.Deinum, yeah this is what I feared. I don't think I am up to the task of writing this handling myself and was hoping something already existed that I could leverage.

Comment: It isn't that hard, it is just a simple class that delegates to the existing `ExceptionHandlerResolver` and you need a small extension to the provided class from Spring and register it as a bean. The components are (mostly) there it requires some wiring together.

Comment: @M.Deinum, are you talking about creating a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` or `AccessDeniedHandler`? I was doing some investigating earlier and it seemed like I had to forcefully "overwrite" the response body.

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        var problemDetail = authException.convertToProblemDetail(); 
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        response.getWriter().write(problemDetail.asJsonString());
    }

Comment: Not if you delegate to the `HandlerExceptionResolver` the annotation driven one should set the status and response itself. You would need an `AccessDeniedHandler` as well.

Comment: So which exception class should the `HandlerExceptionResolver` react to?

`@ExceptionHandler(SomeSpringSecurityException.class)`

Comment: `AuthenticationException` is a bit of a give away (that is in your signature) then decide what to do (check the `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` from Spring for inspiration on method signatures, and you should probably extend that one as well).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254726/discussion-between-stene-and-m-deinum).

Comment: @M.Deinum, The reason for why I asked for which exception, is because "AuthenticationException" does not appear to be thrown at all.

The class: "BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint" has a function `commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)` that receives an AuthenticationException and handles it. So the exception is not thrown further and therefore I believe it cannot be handled by my`@ExceptionHandler(AuthenticationException.class)`

Comment: Read the link I shared earlier... You call the method on the `HandlerExceptionResolver` yourself **with** the excpetion. YOu don't throw it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This answer is thanks to @M.Deinum

**1. There is no built in ProblemDetails-feature for Spring Security**

Since Spring Security does not leverage exception handling from Spring, there is no ProblemDetails support built in.

**2. How to implement this yourself**

One can easily achieve this behavior by implementing two different classes and wiring them up.

Firstly we need to create an ExceptionHandler that can handle the `AuthenticationException.class` from Spring Security

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class AuthenticationExceptionEntityExceptionHandler 
    extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(AuthenticationException.class)
    ProblemDetail handleAuthenticationErrorResponseException() {
        return ProblemDetail.forStatusAndDetail(
            HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,
            "Could not authenticate user"
        );
    }
}
```

Then we need to implement an `AuthenticationEntryPoint.class` which will delegate the exception to the `HandlerExceptionResolver`-implementation

```
public class BearerTokenProblemDetailsAuthenticationEntryPoint 
    implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver;

    public BearerTokenProblemDetailsAuthenticationEntryPoint(
        HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver
    ) {
        this.handlerExceptionResolver = handlerExceptionResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, 
        AuthenticationException authException
    ) {
        handlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(
            request,
            response,
            null,
            authException
        );
    }
}
```

And finally we need to configure our `SecurityFilterChain`-bean

```
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity, NTKeycloakAuthProperties ntKeycloakAuthProperties) throws Exception {

    return httpSecurity
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry -> {
                authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers("/secured/**").authenticated()
                authorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll();
            })
            .oauth2ResourceServer(httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer -> {
                httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.authenticationManagerResolver(
                    new JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver(ntKeycloakAuthProperties.getIssuers())
                );
                // Add the entry point here
                httpSecurityOAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer.authenticationEntryPoint(                        
                    new BearerTokenProblemDetailsAuthenticationEntryPoint(handlerExceptionResolver)
                );
            })
            .build();
}
```

Comment: It will fire only when token was not provided at all. It doesn't handle all jwt errors, like invalid or outdated token

Answer (score -1):

For Spring Security 6 and Spring Boot 3.

```
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("\${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwkSetUri}")
    lateinit var jwkSetUri: String

    @Autowired
    lateinit var cacheManager: CacheManager

    @Autowired
    var authEntryPoint: AuthenticationEntryPoint? = null

    @Autowired
    lateinit var accessDeniedHandler: DefaultAccessDeniedHandler

    private val AUTH_WHITELIST =
        arrayOf(
            "/docs/**",
            "/api-docs/**",
            "/swagger-resources",
            "swagger-resources",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "swagger-resources/**",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "swagger-ui.html",
            "/swagger-ui/**",
            "/csa/api/token", // Actuators
            "/actuator/health/readinessState",
            "actuator/health/readinessState",
            "actuator/health/**",
            "/actuator/health/**",
        )

    @Bean
    fun jwtDecoder(cacheManager: CacheManager): JwtDecoder? {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(jwkSetUri)
            .cache(cacheManager.getCache("jwks"))
            .build()
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http
            .csrf { csrf -> csrf.disable() }
            .cors { cors -> cors.disable() }
            .sessionManagement { sm -> sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) }
            .headers { header -> header.frameOptions { frameOption -> frameOption.disable() } }
            .authorizeHttpRequests { authorize ->
                authorize.requestMatchers(*AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
            }
            .oauth2ResourceServer { oauth2 ->
                oauth2
                    .jwt { jwt -> jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder(cacheManager)) }
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
                    .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
            }
            .securityContext { sc -> sc.requireExplicitSave(true) }
            .exceptionHandling { eh ->
                eh.authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
                eh.accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
            }

        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun jwtAuthenticationConverter(): JwtAuthenticationConverter? {
        val grantedAuthoritiesConverter = JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter()
        grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix("ROLE_")

        val jwtAuthenticationConverter = JwtAuthenticationConverter()
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter)

        return jwtAuthenticationConverter
    }
}


@Component
class DelegatedAuthenticationEntryPoint : AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
    private lateinit var resolver: HandlerExceptionResolver

    @Throws(IOException::class, ServletException::class)
    override fun commence(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        authException: AuthenticationException
    ) {
        resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, authException)
    }
}



@Component
class DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler : AuthenticationFailureHandler {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
    private lateinit var resolver: HandlerExceptionResolver

    @Throws(IOException::class, ServletException::class)
    override fun onAuthenticationFailure(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        exception: AuthenticationException
    ) {
        resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, exception)
    }
}

@Component
class DefaultAccessDeniedHandler : AccessDeniedHandler {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
    private lateinit var resolver: HandlerExceptionResolver

    @Throws(IOException::class, ServletException::class)
    override fun handle(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        accessDeniedException: AccessDeniedException
    ) {
        resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, accessDeniedException)
    }
}
```